# How to stop a CSS animation when it meets the screen edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I created this demo:

http://cristiantraina.altervista.org/boxfall/

When you click, it creates a red falling box.

The problem is that using only css there are no ways to detect the size of the screen, in fact in my demo I specify that the box has to fall for 1000px, regardless of the actual height of the screen.

This is the code of the keyframe:

```
@include keyframes("fall"){
   to{
      top: 1000px;
   }
 }
```

I can't use **bottom:0px;** because I wouldn't know from where to start the fall, and I didn't solve my main problem.

This is the *FallBox.js* script:

```
function FallBox(x, side, parent){
  this.x = x;
  this.parent = parent || $("body");
  this.side = side || Math.random()*200;
  this.createBox();
  this.fall();
}

FallBox.prototype.createBox = function(){
  box = document.createElement('div');
  $box = $(box); // I hate brackets
  $box.addClass("box");
  $box.css({
      width: this.side+"px",
      height: this.side+"px",
      left: this.x+"px",
      top: "-"+(this.side+5)+"px"
  });
  this.box = $box;
}

FallBox.prototype.fall = function(){
  this.parent.append(this.box);
  this.box.addClass("fall");
}
```

I know that I could use **overflow:hidden;** in the parent div, but I don't think that this is the ideal solution. First because a user can have got a screen with a superior height, then because I want to the box stops when it meets the edge, as the border was ground and it shouldn't pass through.

Another solution that I found on the web, it's to use the CSSOM API, but not even [mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) are sure of the compatibilty of these.

So, how can I stop an animation when it meets the screen edge, since javascript fails to inject properties?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use percentages or `vh` units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a css-only solution, you could use the css `calc` feature (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) in combination with `vh` (http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

```js
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("is-dropped");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: top 2s;
}
.box.is-dropped {
  top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You coul use the [`translatey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) function to shift each `div` up by `100%` of its own `height`. That way you would just need 2 rules to change the value of the `top` position without having to worry about `height` in each case.

```js
(function(d,M){
    var  div=d.createElement("div"),
         wait=0,size;
    d.body.addEventListener("click",function(){
      if(!wait){
        wait=1;
        div=div.cloneNode(1);
        div.classList.remove("go");// necessary so that newly created divs don't just get added to the bottom of the page
        size=M.max(M.floor(M.random()*200),50);
        div.style.height=div.style.width=size+"px";
        div.style.left=M.max(M.floor(M.random()*this.offsetWidth)-size,0)+"px";
        this.appendChild(div);
        setTimeout(function(){
          div.classList.add("go");// adding this class starts the animation.
          wait=0;
        },5);
       }
    },0);
})(document,Math);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%}
div{
  background:#000;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  transition:top 2s linear;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transform:translatey(-100%);
}
div.go{
  top:100%;
}
```

---

### ORIGINAL SOLUTION

As the height of the box is being set dynamically in your JavaScript, your CSS isn't going to know the height of each box but that doesn't stop you using the CSS [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the `top` position you want to animate each to, much like you currently do to set its starting `top` position. Here's a quick, rough example, with an alternative solution in the comments that doesn't use `calc()`, if you'd prefer.

```js
var  div=document.createElement("div"),
     wait=0,size;
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if(!wait){
    wait=1;
    div=div.cloneNode(0);
    size=Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random()*200),50);
    div.style.height=div.style.width=size+"px";
    div.style.left=Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.offsetWidth)-size,0)+"px";
    div.style.top="-"+size+"px";
    this.appendChild(div);
    setTimeout(function(){
      div.style.top="calc(100% - "+size+"px)"; /* This is the important bit */
//    div.style.top=document.body.offsetHeight-size+"px"; /* Alternative solution, without using calc() */
      wait=0;
    },5);
   }
},0);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{height:100%}
div{
  background:#000;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  transition:top 2s linear; /* Using a transition instead of an animation */
  position:absolute;
}
```